# Turn off sections of JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a "Manual Override" button that will allow a user to fill in forms of a field manually without auto-complete or the browser doing the math for them. I wanted to have a button that, if left on "No", would run JS but if not would alert them and not run the JS code. Any help in understanding how I'm going about this wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

HTML:

```
    Manual Overide: 
            <label>No<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" 
                        id="manualOverrideNo" value="no" checked /></label>
            <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" 
                        id="manualOverrideYes" value="yes" /></label>
```

JS:

```
   //Manual Override Switch
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) {

//Code For Auto-complete

} else {
        alert("You have turned off Auto-complete");
    }
});
```

Comment: Add a listener to your checkboxes?

Comment: You'll want to check when the actual validation occurs whether or not it should validate. Right now you're just checking on page load.

Comment: on chage event for you check box .  you can do something like this. 
    .autocomplete( "disable" );

Comment: Your if statement would need to be inside the events, not before you bind the events.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that fixed it to where I can now turn the JS auto-complete on and off. Now I just need to figure out how to additionally have it default to start at on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in a JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/9Aknj/

I'm not sure of your whole page context, but instead of having this code execute on DOM load, you may just need to locate at it in the proper location of the event handler that needs to process it.

```
Manual Overide set to NO: 
        <label>No<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" 
                    id="manualOverrideNo" value="no" checked /></label>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" 
                    id="manualOverrideYes" value="yes" /></label>
<br/><br/>
Manual Overide not set to NO: 
        <label>No<input type="radio" name="manualOverride2" 
                    id="manualOverrideNo2" value="no" /></label>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="manualOverride2" 
                    id="manualOverrideYes2" value="yes" checked /></label>
```

Javascript:

```
if($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) {
    //Code For Auto-complete
    alert("AUTOCOMPLETE CODE 1 DO HERE");
} else {
    alert("You have turned off Auto-complete IN FIRST CASE");
}

if($('#manualOverrideNo2').prop('checked')) {
    //Code For Auto-complete
    alert("AUTOCOMPLETE CODE 2 DO HERE");
} else {
    alert("You have turned off Auto-complete IN SECOND CASE");
}
```

**Update:** Based on you latest JSFIDDLE, I have fixed it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/LQW6g/7/

Basically, here is the javascript that attaches the KEYUP event handler and does the computation for you:

```
if($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) {
    $('#footage').bind('keyup', function(){
        var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
        var total = '';
        if(!isNaN(footage)){
            total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
            $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
        } else {
            $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val("");
            alert("You have input invalid number for footage.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr. Fleeman, I have tried to make this code work for my form but it is still not functioning. I have put it into a Fiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/wXL6b/ - any insights into what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided had several js errors, I see you provided a fixed version in the comment to the other question.  Based on that jsfiddle, I provided a fixed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQW6g/7/  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The way you've laid this out, your `if` statement is going to fire right away on page load, which is probably not what you want - instead, you probably need to track the current setting in some way and behave appropriately, so the user can change things at run time.

Here's one approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // var to hold state
    var isManual = false;

    // listener to update state
    $('input[name="manualOverride"]').click(function() {
        isManual = $(this).val() === 'yes';
    });

    // now, in your handlers for the input
    $('#userInput').focus(function() {
        if (isManual) {
            // let the user do things manually
        } else {
            // do automatic stuff
        }
    })
});
```

See a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ff8w/1/

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help but its still not working. I tried to plug in your code as follows: 
$(document).ready(function() {
//var to hold state
 var isManual = false;
 
//listener to update state
 $('input[name="manualOverride"]').click(function() {
  isManual = $(this).val() == 'yes';
 });
 
 //Handlers for input
 $('#manualOverride').focus(function() {
  if(isManual) {
  
  //Code to automate
  
  } else {
 
  alert("You have disabled Auto-Complete")
 }
 
 })
 
});
and tried tinkering around with it but could not get it to work as intended. Any additional clarification would be amazing.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more info about what "working as intended" means in your context.

Comment: @gv0029 - see the fiddle above - if you can add more stuff related to what you're trying to do, that would help.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, my mistake. I checked out the fiddle but am having a tough time wrapping my head around how I could apply that to the form I'm working on. Here is a fiddle to show a snippet of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/LQW6g/3/

Comment: And thanks again for the help. Online tutorials can only help so much sometimes lol.